# How can I automaticaly download images from a SD/CF card on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: photos, camera, sd-card

Yesterday I bought the new 2018 15" MacBook Pro **(until then I was a Windows user for more than 20+ years)** and installed all the software from Canon's EOS Solution Disk (downloaded from Canon's webpage). I am using a Canon 7D Mark II and a Canon 1D X.

On Windows 10 my workflow was that after shooting, I took the SD or CF card out of the camera and plugged it into my card reader, and that started Canon's ImageBrowser EX software, which then automatically started copying my images into the destination folder (with a subfolder that was automatically created based on the date, e.g. /user/Pictures/Canon/2018_09_22).

After that, I proceeded to do my editing. I did not need to plug any of my cameras into the laptop that I was using.

On my new MacBook, I can achieve this only if I plug the whole camera in using a USB cable and run the EOS Utility 3 software when I plug the camera in. Neither does EOS Utility start automatically, nor does it offer the option to download from SD/CF card directly — and apparently, ImageBrowser EX does not even exist for OS X.

So my question is: **How do I achieve that my images are automatically downloaded into subfolders directly from my SD and CF cards when I plug them in the card reader? What software (preferably from Canon) should I use?**

I also posted this question on photo stackexchange and the said I might get better results here...

Comment: Please don't cross-post. If you don't get good answers on the Photography site flag your question for mod attention and ask for having it migrated to AD.

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/101642/how-can-i-automaticaly-download-images-from-a-sd-cf-card-on-a-macbook-pro

Answer (score 2):

Applications > Image Capture

This is the Mac's generic photo importer - it's the actual engine behind Photos.

Launch, insert card, select the card in the list; then bottom left there is a drop menu so you can tell it what automatic action to perform.
This is where I'm uncertain as I'm a Nikon user, not Canon.

[image]

<sup>Drop menu artificially moved across so you can see the section underneath</sup>

From here you can set whether or not to auto-launch any capable app, or use Image Capture itself. I just import to the same folder each time then move after I've done initial edits, but from here you could tell it to auto-launch your Canon software & it could then take over the import & file structure..

One caveat - if you reformat the SD card, it will be recognised as a new device each time you do. The Mac treats each card as a separate entity & always knows which card it is, even if you have several with the same name [which also means you need to set up the same workflow for each card, the first time]. Reformatting breaks that association.